# Python generator that can do cumulative sum of the previous elements

Tags: python, generator

I am working with Python3 and trying to create a oneliner that creates a generator that can return the cumulative sum of members of a list.

For example, given the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the generator expression should return `1, 3, 6, 10` in each call to `next`.

I know how to do this with several lines of code. I would like to find a way to do it as a Python oneliner. The problem I find is how to access the previous values.

Comment: `itertools.accumulate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The following one-liner will return the desired result:

```
[i for i in itertools.accumulate(x)]
```

This will return:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: Or simply `list(accumulate(x))`.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to solve this with a generator

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
[sum(lst[:n+1]) for n in range(len(lst))]
```

but this in inefficient, since every sum is recomputed from scratch. An efficient approach would require an accumulator variable, which is not possible in a comprehension.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to solve this with a generator.

Comment: this is a generator, just strip the outer [...]